Is there a connection between prime factorizations and the statistical constant 1.6449?
I've noticed a convergence pattern in prime factorizations and unique combinations, which appears to stabilize around 1.6449.
Setup:
Let $n$ be an integer and define $f(n)$ as the prime factorization of $n$. For each $n$, I calculated:

Unique Prime Factors: The count of distinct primes in the factorization of $n$.

Unique Prime Combinations: The count of distinct factorizations (ignoring multiplicities).


I then computed the following ratio:
$$ R(n) = \frac{n}{\text{Unique Prime Combinations of } n} $$
Observation:
This ratio converges to approximately 1.6449 (especially for larger values of $n$).
For example, at $n = 100,000$:
$R(100,000)≈1.6449$
Similarly, at $n = 1,000,000$:
$R(1,000,000)≈1.6449$
Question:
Does this ratio have any known significance in number theory or prime distribution?
Could this value represent a new constant related to prime behavior?
Is there a deeper connection between prime factorization growth and random distributions, similar to how 1.6449 is critical in normal distribution?
Any insights or related research would be appreciated!

Explanation of Unique Prime Combinations
For each integer  we consider its prime factorization and the different combinations of prime factors, ignoring exponents for uniqueness.
Examples:

For $n = 6$:


Prime factorization: $6 = 2 × 3$
Unique combination: {2,3} (one combination)


For $n = 12$:


Prime factorization: $12 = 2^2 × 3$
We ignore powers for combinations, so this is still {2,3}
Unique combination: No new combination since {2,3} was already counted.


For $n = 30$:


Prime factorization: $30 = 2 × 3 × 5$
Unique combination {2,3,5} (new combination).

Approach in Mathematical Terms:
We can formalize this by saying that for each $$ the prime factorization gives us a set of primes $S_n$.  We track new sets $S_n$ only when they haven't been encountered before, regardless of exponents.  This results in a growing set of unique prime combinations as $n$ increases.
How It Relates to the Ratio:
The ratio is calculated by dividing $n$ by the number of unique prime combinations up to $n$, with each new set contributing to the count.
Screenshot of table of $n$ for 1 thorough 32.  Note that the ratio does not stabilize for a bit and jumps around a bit in the start.

Here is how it looks out at $n$ = 10000

Detailed breakdown of combinations for first 30 iterations.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This is not an Answer.  It is an attempt to restate the Question.  (Originally, it was not an Answer.  Subsequently, an Answer was added to the end.)
For $n$ in the integers, let
$$  n = \prod_{j=1}^h p_j^{e_j}  $$
be the prime factorization of $n$, where the $p_j$ are distinct prime numbers, $h$ is the number of distinct primes dividing $n$, and the $e_j$ are positive integers.  Using the above notation, for each $n$,
$$  S_n = \{p_j\}_{j = 1}^h  $$
is the set of primes dividing $n$.
Now define
$$  U_n = \{S_i\}_{i=1}^n  \text{,}  $$
the collection of $S_i$ for $i=1$ through $n$.

Note: Using a set means duplicates are discarded.  Any two members of this set, $S_i$ and $S_j$, have $S_i \neq S_j$.  So we are counting unique prime divisor sets.

Note that sometimes $U_n = U_{n-1}$ when the prime divisors of $n$ are also the prime divisors of some smaller integer.  For instance, for $q \in \Bbb{N}$, $U_{4q} = U_{4q-1}$ because $S_{4q} = S_{2q}$.
Let us study
$$  \frac{n}{|U_n|}  \text{,}  $$
the number $n$ divided by the number of distinct $S_j$ for $j \in [1,n]$.

Note: there may be an off-by-one error here.  Maybe you mean $n/|U_{n-1}|$.  You should check this.

Numerical experimentation suggests
$$  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{|U_n|}  $$
exists and is some number near $1.6449$.  Can we show this limit exists and find its value?

Solution (added later)...
Pick $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and consider the set $\{m : S_m = S_n\}$.  The least element of this set is the product of the primes in $S_n$ because any other element of this set has the same primes in its prime factorization, but at least one of them has a power greater than $1$ (and since primes are greater than $1$ multiplying by one makes the product larger).  That is, $|U_n|$ counts naturals with square-free factorizations in $[1,n]$.
Therefore, $|U_n|/n$ is the proportion of naturals in $[1,n]$ that are square-free.  ($Q(n)$ there is our $|U_n|$.)  It is a standard result that
$$  |U_n| = \frac{n}{\zeta(2)} + O(\sqrt{n})  \text{,}  $$
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function and the error term is expressed in big $O$ notation.  So we have
$$  \frac{|U_n|}{n} = \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} + O(1/\sqrt{n})  \text{.}  $$
Since $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$ and $1/\sqrt{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, we have
$$  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{|U_n|} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} = 1.644\,934\,066\,848\,226\,436\dots  \text{.}  $$

It turned out that he was counting the squarefree numbers up to $n,$  and dividing $n$ by that count, so that the limiting ratio is $\pi^2 / 6$  SEE  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155574/discussion-on-question-by-joseph-astrahan-is-there-a-connection-between-prime-fa

@WillJagy : I think that's congruent to what is written above.  Do you think there's any point in keeping this Answer around?

Sure, especially if you can   add an explanation as to how  to get squarefree numbers out of his description.  All I can see:  take the set of primes up to $n.$   Count all subsets with product no larger than $n,$  including the empty set (gives $1$)

Wow, I like how you broke that down! I will need some time to digest that all but I think I see what you are doing, are you saying as n approaches infinity n divided by unique factors of n is equal to pi squared divided by 6, this is indeed what I am trying to confirm and understand more.  Technically there is no square numbers in “Un” because they are not counted in the list for each value of n

So $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |\mu(k)|\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \mu(k)^2\right)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$$ where $k, n$ are positive integers, $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function, and $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\mu(k)|}{k^s}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu (k)^2}{k^s}=\frac{\zeta (s)}{\zeta (2 s)},,\quad\Re(s)>1$$ (also see OEIS entry A008966)?

This is consistent with the primary growth term $\frac{6 x}{\pi^2}$ in the explicit formula for $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^x \mu(k)^2$$ given by the residue of $\left(\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2 s)} \frac{x^s}{s}\right)$ at $s=1$ since $\underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}} \left(\frac{1}{x} \frac{6 x}{\pi^2}\right)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

Also see OEIS entry A013928 for the number of (positive) square-free numbers $<n$.
